# AND IF Excel formula returning incorrect value

Tags: excel, if-statement, excel-formula, count, excel-2010

I'm trying to write a formula that will count number of edits in my data. Column A will tell how many times the data has been edited using

`=IF(AND($D5468=$D5467,$G5468<>$G5467),0)+1`

formula. Basically what I wanted is, if value in column D is the same and value in column G is the same, it will count as one. And will continuously count as the date change. My issue is that in the middle of my counting "Highlighted in Yellow" I wanted the 2nd one to remain as 2 since it is just the same with the previous one but it is returning to one. Is there any way I can solve this?

[image]

Comment: How does that formula end up returning 3, 4 5 and 6? That's not possible. Either you'r not showing the whole formula or your sample data is flawed.

Comment: I don't think it is possible to count the number if edits by formula. This probably needs to be done via vba.

Comment: That is all my formula didn't hide anything. I hide unused field in my excel but not related to the formula.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming both of your columns are sorted. You need to paste below formula in cell A2 and make A1 entry manually(i.e. 1).

```
=IF($D2=$D1,IF($G2=$G1,A1,A1+1),1)
```

Comment: WOW thanks!!! i did not change the 1st  cell but it still worked. thank you so much